# How do I run a script automatically after EC2 instance recovery?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance (Windows based) with an application server running on it. I would like to create alarms and auto-recover the instance if the status check fails. However, it's very important for me that the application server is run after the instance recovers. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of whether auto-recover is used, you should configure your server to always automatically run your application upon startup. This way, you can always Reboot your instance and the application should start running.

The method varies by operating system (which was not stated in your question) and can be easily found via web search.